# "Almost-structured" 2d quadrilateral mesh in Gmsh

Tags: 2d, mesh

I'd like to generate a two-dimensional quadrilateral mesh using Gmsh. The mesh should be such that its cells are "as quadratic as possible" with a given edge length. That is, if the geometry is simple, I'd expect a perfectly structured grid, and if the geometry is more complex, I'd only expect local distortion.

Consider the following minimal example:

```
lc = 1;

Point(1) = {0, 0, 0, lc};
Point(2) = {10, 0,  0, lc} ;
Point(3) = {10, 4, 0, lc} ;
Point(4) = {0,  4, 0, lc} ;

Point(5) = {1,  1, 0, lc} ;
Point(6) = {3,  1, 0, lc} ;
Point(7) = {2,  2, 0, lc} ;


Line(1) = {1,2} ;
Line(2) = {3,2} ;
Line(3) = {3,4} ;
Line(4) = {4,1} ;

Line(5) = {5,6} ;
Line(6) = {6,7} ;
Line(7) = {7,5} ;


Line Loop(1) = {4,1,-2,3} ;
Line Loop(2) = {5,6,7} ;

Plane Surface(1) = {1,2} ;
```

The above yields a highly unstructured mesh, despite there being only a small hole in an otherwise simple and rectangular geometry:

[image: Mesh generated using above code.]

What I'd have in mind is something like this (taken from Automesh2d's web site, a commercial mesh generator):

[image: Example taken from a commercial mesh generator ( http://www.automesh2d.com/automesh2dintroduction.files/image010.jpg )]

Can I get a similar "quasi-structured," two-dimensional quadrilateral mesh also using Gmsh (or for that matter, using any open source software)? I'd really appreciate any support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible using Transfinite Lines. You define a Transfinite Line between certain points, in your case between the corner points of your large rectangle. While doing so, you can specify how many nodes should be included on this line. If you choose the same number of nodes on the opposing lines of the rectangle, you should be doing fine. Recombine the surface and you're done.
In this simple [YouTube-Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1FyiBBuN98), you'll be guided through it step-by-step.
I have quickly tried a similar geometry to yours, this is what I get:

[image]

[Mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMc2n.png)